# Chi Square Test - Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Tags: r, chi-squared

I'm trying to do a Chi-Square Test on a data frame (a CSV) as below:

|  | Lion | Elephant |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lion | 32 | 19 |
| Elephant | 11 | 27 |

And I have use the below code for the analysis:

```
aovdata <- read.csv("Jungle.csv", header = T)
aovdata

attach (aovdata)

Lion <- as.factor("Lion")
Elephant <- as.factor("Elephant")
class(Lion)
class(Elephant)

str(aovdata)

model <- chisq.test(aovdata)
model
```

then I receive the error

```
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

can someone please let me know where have I got it wrong and what's the solution?

Thanks,

EDITED* Apologise I didn't write it clearly. So the table represents the sequence of animal observed between camera one and two. (i.e. Lion-Lion ; Lion-Elephant ; Elephant-Lion ; Elephant-Elephant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do the `chisq.test` on the data itself as both are numeric columns

```
chisq.test(aovdata)
```

Regarding the use of

```
Lion <- as.factor("Lion")
```

It is just creating a string "Lion" as `factor` and storing it in `Lion` object name

#### data

```
aovdata <- structure(list(Lion = c(32, 11), Elephant = c(19, 27)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Lion", 
"Elephant"))
```

Comment: thank you for helping. So do you mean in this case, we don't create a factor (i.e. as.factor) ? But in this data set, it is counting the combination of Lion- Lion , Lion - Elephant, Elephant-Lion , and Elephant-Elephant.

Comment: @Spybuster `chisq.test` can work in both numeric and factor.  I assumed your have only 2 column, row with row.names.  The way you create `factor` on string will not work i.e. if you are creating factor it would be `aovdata[] <- lapply(aovdata, factor)`

Comment: thanks! it works perfectly!

so the P value is <0.05 , fail to reject Null Hypothesis --> Habitats of Lion and Elephant overlapse I suppose?

Comment: depends on your alpha